# R - [DESeq2] - How use TMM normalized counts (from EdgeR) in inputs for DESeq2?

Tags: r, rna-seq

I have several RNAseq samples, from different experimental conditions. After sequencing, and alignment to reference genome, I merged the raw counts to get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> df_merge
           T0   DJ21   DJ24   DJ29   DJ32   Rec2   Rec6   Rec9
G10       421    200    350    288    284    198    314    165
G1000   17208  10608  11720  11421  10142  10768  10331   6121
G10000     37     16     19     21     28     12      9      4
G10002     45     13     44     27     12     35     74     14
G10003    136     79    162    429    184    112    192    162
G10004     54    162     73    169    102    300    429    180
G10006      1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
G10007      3      4      7      2      1      1      1      0
G1001    9030   8366  10608  13604   9808  10654  11663   7985
...       ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
```

I use EdgeR to perform TMM normalization, which is the normalization method I want to use, and is not available in DESeq2. For that I use the following script:

```
## Normalisation by the TMM method (Trimmed Mean of M-value)
dge <- DGEList(df_merge)                        # DGEList object created from the count data
dge2 <- calcNormFactors(dge, method = "TMM")    # TMM normalization calculate the normfactors
```

I then obtain the following normalization factors:

```
> dge2$samples
     group  lib.size norm.factors
T0       1 129884277    1.1108130
DJ21     1 110429304    0.9453988
DJ24     1 126410256    1.0297216
DJ29     1 123008035    1.0553169
DJ32     1 118968544    0.9927826
Rec2     1 119000510    0.9465131
Rec6     1 114775318    1.0053686
Rec9     1  90693946    0.9275454
```

I normalize the raw counts with the normalization factors:

```
# Normalized pseudo counts are obtained with the function cpm and stored in a data frame:
pseudo_TMM <- log2(cpm(dge2) + 1)                        
df_TMM <- melt(pseudo_TMM, id = rownames(raw_counts_wn))
names(df_TMM)[1:2] <- c ("id", "sample")
df_TMM$method <- rep("TMM", nrow(df_TMM))
```

And I get TMM normalized counts, in a new dataframe:

```
> pseudo_TMM
                 T0        DJ21        DJ24        DJ29        DJ32        Rec2        Rec6        Rec9
G10     1.970115581  1.54384913  1.88316953  1.68642670  1.76745996  1.46356074  1.89575666  1.56628879
G1000   6.910138402  6.68101996  6.50839579  6.47542172  6.44077248  6.59395683  6.50032388  6.20481983
G10000  0.329354263  0.20571418  0.19656414  0.21632677  0.30692404  0.14605339  0.10835095  0.06701850
G10002  0.391657436  0.16931112  0.42010652  0.27261134  0.13960084  0.39037793  0.71483462  0.22209164
G10003  0.958011321  0.81287356  1.16642722  2.10593537  1.35494357  0.99592405  1.41354030  1.54881003
G10004  0.458675608  1.35147467  0.64230087  1.20281148  0.89809414  1.87320592  2.23810756  1.65064058
G10006  0.009964976  0.00000000  0.01104103  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
G10007  0.029690785  0.05424318  0.07556948  0.02205789  0.01216343  0.01275200  0.01244875  0.00000000
G1001   5.990679797  6.34224022  6.36623615  6.72515956  6.39302663  6.57876150  6.67346174  6.58377191
  ...           ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
```

And this is where it gets complicated. Usually I do my DGE analysis with DESeq2 with the DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount() and DESeq() functions, which itself runs an RLE normalization. Now I would like to use DESeq2 directly to do the DGE analysis on my already normalized data. I saw that the DeseqDataSet object could be created from a matrix with the DESeqDataSetFromMatrix() function.
If someone has already succeeded in using DESeq2 with data from TMM normalization, I would appreciate some advice

Answer (score 0):

I remembered I saw something about how the norm factors must be converted to the  appropriate size factors in DESeq2 and I found the thread on Bioconductor:

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/p133964/

It was suggested to read the following in order to get a better understanding of the conversion necessary:

https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0157022

Essentially in the supplementary info, they give the following code snippet for the conversion:

```
tmm <- calcNormFactors(geneCount, method="TMM")
N <- colSums(geneCount) #vector of library size
tmm.counts <- N*tmm/exp(mean(log(N*tmm)))
```

Cheers